# Angular js api url in loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/xxx/xxx/xas'}).success(function(data) {        
    $scope.website = data.websites;
    });

$http({method: 'GET',url: '/xx/xasxxx?websiteId='+$scope.website.websiteId}).success(function(data) {
     $scope.onlinedata1 = data.coupons;                      
 });
```

I try to get websiteID from top url and pass that id in to 2nd url .my json data structure

```
"websites":[{
     "websiteName":"Flipkart",
     "websiteId":"1",
      },
      {
     "websiteName":"asas",
     "websiteId":"5",
      }]
```

Try to pass every id one by one. I am using  AngularJS v1.2.17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the second HTTP call within the success callback of the first one:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/xxx/xxx/xas'}).success(function(data) {        
    $scope.website = data.websites;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.websites.length; i++)
    {
        $http({method: 'GET',url: '/xx/xasxxx?websiteId='+data.websites[i].websiteId}).success(function(data) {
            $scope.onlinedata1 = data.coupons;                      
        });
    }
});
```

This can be simplified considering that your requests are GETs:

```
$http.get('/xxx/xxx/xas')
    .then(function(res) {        
        for (var i = 0; i < res.data.websites.length; i++)
        {
            $http.get('/xx/xasxxx?websiteId='+res.data.websites[i].websiteId)
                .then(function(res) {
                    $scope.onlinedata1 = res.data.coupons;                      
            });
        }
});
```

Please note that the above will issue one request for each website returned by the API. If you have control over the API you might want to consider accepting multiple website IDs on the second URL resource (`/xx/xasxxx?websiteIds=1,5,7,12,56`) so as to limit the number of requests issued by the client.

Comment: i try this but +$scope.website.websiteId pass "undefined"

Comment: you are right, i totally forgot about the `for` loop here. I have edited my answer.

Comment: All url json data how to store in same variable $scope.onlinedata1

Answer (score 0):

Use $q - service in module ng
A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing.